# Recommendations for good SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) examples/samples for ETL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, ssis

I'm looking for some decent examples/samples using SSIS to do some ETL from one SQL Server database to another not necessarily within the same instance.

The idea is to migrate rows of data with their heirarchies (relationships) from one OLTP database to another.

There are some advantages SSIS offers us which makes it a good choice as the migration/ETL platform (amongst other things it needs to be fully configurable and able to be executed on an automated schedule).

Does anyone know of any decent samples/examples besides the MS community samples (on Codeplex)?

Edit: I've also had a look at http://www.sqlis.com/ though I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 1):

There are Microsoft Tutiorials on how to use each Task Component and concept available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141767.aspx

You will likely need to review several tutorials in order to aquire the knowledge to create a solution for your specific scenario.

Another excellent source of SSIS tips is Jamie Thomson's Blog. The man is a bit of wizard with SSIS:

http://blogs.conchango.com/jamiethomson/

Once you have had a look over the material, if you require specific assistance then feel free to drop a line.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good articles/tutorials from Microsoft on ETL:

1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671624.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Sql Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/) and Sql Server World Users' Group ([SSWUG](http://www.sswug.org/)) sites. If you can't find the examples/tutorials/experts you need in those two places, give up coding and take up cooking, because those sites are treasure troves!